# Convert code - not work

Tags: php

There is a code.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'adding_image_dimensions' );

function adding_image_dimensions( $content ) {

    preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]+>/i', $content, $images);

    if (count($images) < 1)
        return $content;

foreach ($images[0] as $image) {
    preg_match_all( '/(alt|title|src|width|class|id|height)=("[^"]*")/i', $image, $img );

    if ( !in_array( 'src', $img[1] ) )
        continue;

    if ( !in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) || !in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ) {
        $src = $img[2][ array_search('src', $img[1]) ];
        $alt = in_array( 'alt', $img[1] ) ? ' alt=' . $img[2][ array_search('alt', $img[1]) ] : '';
        $title = in_array( 'title', $img[1] ) ? ' title=' . $img[2][ array_search('title', $img[1]) ] : '';
        $class = in_array( 'class', $img[1] ) ? ' class=' . $img[2][ array_search('class', $img[1]) ] : '';
        $id = in_array( 'id', $img[1] ) ? ' id=' . $img[2][ array_search('id', $img[1]) ] : '';

        list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( str_replace( "\"", "" , $src ) );
        $html = '';

        if (($width != 0) || ($height != 0)) {
            $html = ' width="%d" height="%d" ';
        }

        $image_tag = sprintf( '<img loading="lazy" src=%s%s%s%s%s' . $html . '/>', $src, $alt, $title, $class, $id, $width, $height );
        $content = str_replace($image, $image_tag, $content);
    }
}

return $content;
}
```

I changed it a little. So that everything fits into the database at once, and not constantly generated on the fly.

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'adding_image_dimensions' );

function adding_image_dimensions( $content ) {

$content = $content['post_content'];

    preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]+>/i', $content, $images);

    if (count($images) < 1)
        return $content;

foreach ($images[0] as $image) {...
```

But the code doesn't work for some reason :-(

Im use WordPress 5.7.2, Classic Editor. And in my articles I have a lot of pictures so inscribed.

```
<a href="https://....jpg" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="test title"><img class="test class" alt="test alt" src="https://....jpg"></a>
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  "Doesn't work" unfortunately does not really mean anything.  Add more detail regarding the exact problem to craft a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I changed it a little.

> But the code doesn't work for some reason :-(

You should explain what exactly happened or did not happen that should have happened, rather than simply saying "doesn't work".

But anyway, if the first and fifth lines below were the only changes you applied in the code:

```php
add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'adding_image_dimensions' );

function adding_image_dimensions( $content ) {

$content = $content['post_content'];
```

Then that indeed would not give you the expected outcome (e.g. no `<img>` tag would be replaced because the second `preg_match_all()` call would fail), and here's why:

1. The function is now hooked on the [`wp_insert_post_data` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_data/), so the function should return an array of post data, and yet in your code, the fifth line (i.e. `$content = $content['post_content'];`) actually changes the return value to a string.
2. The `$content['post_content']` value is slashed (e.g. `src="..."` becomes `src=\"...\"`), so you should first unslash the value and then slash it back after the image tags are processed.

### How can you fix the issues

To make the `adding_image_dimensions()` function works with the `wp_insert_post_data` filter instead, you can try the following:

```php
// 1: Rename the $content to $data
function adding_image_dimensions( $data ) {
    // 2: Unslash the post content.
    $content = wp_unslash( $data['post_content'] );

    preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]+>/i', $content, $images);

    if (count($images) < 1) {
        // 3: Return the $data and not $content.
        return $data;
    }

    foreach ($images[0] as $image) {
        // ... your code here.
    }

    // 4: Slash back the post content.
    $data['post_content'] = wp_slash( $content );

    // 5: Return the $data and not $content.
    return $data;
}
```

#### Alternate Solution (without having to "convert" or modify the custom function)

1. Remove the `add_filter( 'the_content', 'adding_image_dimensions' );`
2. Call the *original* `adding_image_dimensions()` function in the `wp_insert_post_data` hook:

   ```php
   // * use add_filter() and not add_action()
   add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'my_wp_insert_post_data' );

   function my_wp_insert_post_data( $data ) {
       $content = adding_image_dimensions( wp_unslash( $data['post_content'] ) ); // pass an *unslashed* content
       $data['post_content'] = wp_slash( $content ); // then slash back the content
       return $data;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. But doesn't work((( Please looking. A freshly installed test site.

`http://sitework.epizy.com`

FTP Hostname: `ftpupload.net`
FTP Username: `epiz_28828400`
FTP Password: `kfzX88ywI211oY`

Wordpress Console:
Username: `admin`
Password: `12345678`

Code this `...wp-content/themes/iconic-one/functions.php`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to unslash/slash the post content.. but anyway, please see the revised answer and let me know. PS: I didn't test on your test site.

Comment: Also, change the passwords on your test site ***right now***.

Comment: I agreed with @PatJ and seemed like people have been messing with your site (via FTP), so don't just give away your FTP password or even WordPress (admin) password. Also, I suggest you to develop locally (on `localhost` in your computer) or use a better hosting site or package.. e.g. Amazon EC2 which offers a free trial..

Comment: This is how it works. Thank you for help! You are the best!